# ¿Es mala práctica utilizar id como url?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

¿Es mala práctica utilizar un id como referencia en la url para mostrar los datos de un producto especificiado como por ejemplo "www.productos.es/producto/3" ? tengo entendido no es buena práctica que el usuario sepa las ids, de ser así, ¿que forma sería la conveniente?

Comment: Puedes usar un id, pero no por medio de métodos GET, sino POST, entonces así el usuario no ve los ids.

Comment: @RandallSandoval GET o POST es información no cifrada, que el usuario puede capturar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depende de si ese id es información sensible o no.

Por ejemplo en un catálogo de productos con un entero autoincrementable, si se tiene un producto con id 100, ¿es realemente necesario ocultar al usuario que existe un producto con id 101?

En cambio en otro caso por ejemplo si se tiene un id de usuario por ejemplo podría ser conveniente no identificarlos con un número autoincrementable sino con un GUID.

Otro caso con id no autogenerados:

Imaginemos una página sobre paises donde la url contiene el id que es el código alfa-2 del ISO 3166-1 del país por ejemplo: `ES` para españa. No tiene ningún sentido ocultar este id.

En cambio por ejemplo si el id es el SSN (Social Security number) de un empleado en una página de recursos humanos, en este caso si tendría sentido ocultarlo y mostrar un GUID en su lugar.

Estos son solo ejemplos tal vez un ena app un mismo campo de una misma entidad convenga ocultar sus identificadores y en otra no.

De todas maneras esto **no es un sustituto** de tener implementado un mecanismo de **autorización** que permita ingresar solo a los usuarios válidos a las urls correspondientes.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, en el caso que quiera por ejemplo hacer una url con el id autoincrement de mi tabla empleado, que no tiene nada que ver con información sensible del empleado, como su DNI. No haría falta ocultar su id?

Comment: @jlgf si tus empleados se loguean y su id es usada en el sistema en algun momento para verificar su indentidad, acceso a recursos, etc. esa ID es un dato que no debes mostrar.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como lo explica Carlos Muñoz en su respuesta, depende del tipo de información, en todo caso el adjetivo **"seguro"** siempre será relativo.

Si deseas ocultar tus Id en Laravel, puedes hacerlo con Sluggable: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

La instalación se hace con composer y tan solo hay que agregar algunos parámetros al modelo:

```
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableScopeHelpers;    

class Post extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    use SluggableScopeHelpers;    

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Para obtener el objeto, lo haces con: `Post::findBySlugOrFail($slug)`

Incluso puedes usar Route Model Binding con sluggable: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/blob/master/ROUTE-MODEL-BINDING.md

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso este paquete para trabajar con los ids sin necesidad de agregar el campo slug en tablas que no son necesarios.
[integer-hashids](https://github.com/amamarul/integer-hashids)
despues de instalarlo podés utilizar por ejemplo los helpers:

- encode()
  *con la configuración por defecto*
  `encode($id)`
  *con una conexion personalizada (Ej. "producto")*
  `encode($id,'producto')`
- decode()
  *con la configuración por defecto*
  `decode($hashid)`
  *con una conexion personalizada (Ej. "producto")*
  `decode($hashid,'producto')`

Este package esta armado para poder agregarle prefijos a tus ids (o no) y por si queres solo numeros en tus hashes ids.
Esto es util por ejemplo para codigos de productos.
Y en el caso de querer `ids` alfanumericos tambien los podés armar.
Podés tener tantas conexiones como quieras, incluso podes tener uno por cada modelo.
Utilizando esto no necesitas agregar un campo a la tabla y cuando recibís el `$id` del request lo decodificas y listo.
Obviamente debes enviar en las responses tambien este $id codificado.
Pero podes incluso agregar en el modelo un `mutator` y hacer un `appends`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo generar un hash md5 para los ids sensibles. Normalmente cojo un valor o varios valores que forman el registro y los concateno y luego los concateno con un numero generado aleatorio y la funcion time(). Después todo va en un hash md5.

La desventaja es que ocupan 32 caracteres en la bd, pero por otro lado no son nada "deducibles" si se quiere trastear con peticiones get y post. Un ejemplo:

```
$id_usuario =md5(md5(time().rand(1,999999)).md5($dni.$nombre.$cif_empresa));
```